# Working with 2 Entity Framework ASP.Net API

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have 2 Entity Framework entities but I can't access the last entity that I created. I'm working with 2 databases so I created 2 entities. 1 can be access but the other one can't.

The error that show are

The entity type `Ms_User` is not part of the model for the current context.

```
using (var db = new mobilekeyEntities())
{
    //Check if User exist
    var userDb = db.Ms_User.Where(n => n.UserID.Equals(username) && n.Password.Equals(password)).FirstAsync();

    if (userDb != null)
        {
           identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
        }
    }
```

Please tell me what I did wrong or need to add to access the other entity.
Thank you

Comment: I think you missed `SaveChanges`

Comment: `mobilekeyEntities()` is one of your Entity names, can you verify it is the one which contains `Ms_User` class? If not, try accessing (valid) tables from both entities once to make sure the connection is set correctly.

Comment: As far as I can tell @Eldho is correct. Step through your code and see if `userDb` exists/is set/the `if` statement returns `true` . If so, the problem is with saving the data in the other entity. Well, the problem with unsaved changes *occurs for sure*, the question here is *is that the only one?* If the variable `userDb` isn't being set it means that there's a problem with your context/database definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure the dbset instance in your dbcontext class is same.

```
public DbSet<Ms_User> Ms_Users{get;set;}
```

then the query should be like this

```
var userDb = db.Ms_Users.Where(n => n.UserID.Equals(username) && n.Password.Equals(password)).FirstAsync();
```